# Nuget - Ability to specify which package dependencies to exclude from the package being added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

My problem is this:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website project which references many Nuget public packages. These packages provide some additional functionality to my project but are not mandatory for the project to run. Now I've made a Nuget package myself based on this project. When I include this package in another ASP.NET MVC 3 website project all those Nuget packages referenced by my, should I say *template* project, are also added into the destination project.

That is something I don't really want or like. Preferably I would like the ability to choose which packages get in and which not.

I think the problem stems from the fact that Nuget treats all the package dependencies the same, while I think there should be a way to tell which package dependency is mandatory and which one is useful but optional.

Is there anything like that in Nuget (currently using the latest 1.5 version)?

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of non-mandatory dependencies you have?

Maybe you could leave the optional dependencies out, and let the user include them (possibly via NuGet) if they want them?

Comment: You can't do this today. Make sure you file an issue so we can look for some way to solve this for the next version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using an automating tool for creating the package. However, there's a solution and it is in NuGet Package Explorer (http://npe.codeplex.com/).
Open your package in NPE and edit package's metadata

> Edit -> Edit Metadata

Near the bottom of the panel is the Dependencies section. Here you can remove any unwanted dependency you have put with your automating tool.
You may also want to see what these dependencies look like in XML - use

> Edit -> Edit Metadata Source